# java InputStream read zeros from socket

Tags: java

We have got strange issue when create 100 threads and in each create connection and read big message:

```
socket = new Socket(host, port);
socket.setSoTimeout(3_000);
socketConnection = new SocketConnection();
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
byte[] bb = new byte[15_000];
int r = in.read(bb, 0, 15_000);
assert r == 15_000;
```

Usually all is fine, but some time we've found zeros inside bb. The lenght of zeros depends of MTU. For example:

1. When MTU = 9001 (it is Amazon server's setting by default, Ubuntu 20.04)

bb[0] = 1 // means some real data in position 0

bb[1] = 1 // means some real data in position 1

...

bb[8946] = 1 // means some real data in position 8946

bb[8947] = 0 // means got zero in position 8947 (it is wrong! not really sent)

bb[8948] = 0 // means got zero in position 8948 (it is wrong! not really sent)

bb[8949] = 0 // means got zero in position 8949 (it is wrong! not really sent)

...

bb[14999] = 0 // means got zero in position 14999 (it is wrong! not really sent)

The number 8947 = MTU - 54 (I suggest 54 is some header) = 9001 - 54

2. If set MTU = 5000 and change the code:

```
socket = new Socket(host, port);
socket.setSoTimeout(3_000);
socketConnection = new SocketConnection();
InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
int size = 15_000;
while (size > 0) {
 int currentChunkSize = Math.min(size, 4096);
 byte[] bb = new byte[currentChunkSize];
 int r = in.read(bb, 0, currentChunkSize);
 assert r == currentChunkSize;
 size -= currentChunkSize;
}
```

Then we got:

bb[0] = 1 // means some real data in position 0

bb[1] = 1 // means some real data in position 1

...

bb[4946] = 1 // means some real data in position 4946

bb[4947] = 0 // means got zero in position 4947 (it is wrong! not really sent)

bb[4948] = 0 // means got zero in position 4948 (it is wrong! not really sent)

bb[4949] = 0 // means got zero in position 4949 (it is wrong! not really sent)

...

bb[8197] = 0 // means got zero in position 8197 (it is wrong! not really sent)

bb[8198] = 1 // means some real data in position 8198

...

bb[14444] = 1 // means some real data in position 14444

The number 4946 = MTU - 54 = 5000 - 54

By the way, packets weren't lost. The second case shows that bb[8198] got byte was sent at 4947 postion. So in.read() return zeros between the real packets.

It is hard to repeat, happen rarely and only when working over the real network (never happened local). And got it only on the amazon servers.

It is problem because we can't be sure is it real zero block (such data) or the issue. Any ideas what is it?

Comment: Are you using the `-ea` switch to enable assertions? I doubt the read has filled the buffer completely, you're ignoring the return value `r` completely and assuming the buffer is full.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.

Comment: You might want to look at other questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24791360/why-doesnt-inputstream-fill-the-array-fully on how to work with the `read()` method which accepts an array argument.